# problem trying to initiate a console with WSL 2 in CMDER

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmder

I have this error just trying to use WSL from cmder

```
wslbridge error: failed to start backend process
note: backend error output: -v: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matchi ng `''
-v: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

does anyone how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new profile with the command `wsl.exe`.

[image]

Taken from https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1930#issuecomment-512882561; it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody having problems with this, I finally figured it out by setting a new task command of:

```
wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

In my case, I had two versions of WSL installed and it wouldn't take the newer in Cmder for anything—it always loaded the `~` directory of my older install. You can use the file browser and go to directory `\\wsl$` to see which version of WSL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

It is a ConEmu thing. The whole WSL part is for WSL version 1, I guess you are running WSL version 2?

You need a new version of cygwin1.dll
Grab one here: https://cygwin.com/snapshots/
Go to vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\wsl and replace the dll.

You need wslbridge 2:
Grab it here: https://github.com/Biswa96/wslbridge2/releases (the cygwin version)
Copy the content to the same directory: vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\wsl

Now edit your WSL bash task:
Replace the part "conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl" with "conemu-cyg-64.exe %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl\wslbridge2.exe"

It works now.