# Can't open terminal in Jetbrains GoLand

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, goland

From the moment I work on Ubuntu WSL2 I'm facing problem with local terminal in IDE (Jetbrains GoLand) - I can't open it.
When I try to run a terminal, it only opens for a fraction of a second and gives this error:

```
bash -l: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash -l: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

It only happens if directory is located in Ubuntu VM, if file is located in casual Windows disc problem disappears. Moreover, I can work with Golang through Ubuntu WSL terminal, but local IDE terminal is not cooperating.

**Versions**: GoLand 2022.2.2; Ubuntu 22.04 (2); WSL 2; Win10;

*File/Settings/Tools/Terminal*

[image]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of _File | Settings | Tools | Terminal_.

Comment: @s0xzwasd  just edited the post with screenshot. (After removing Win version of go from GOPATH, terminal works, but dunno if this is reason)

Answer (score 2):

You can try, for testing as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72955520/6309) (which, for a different context, exhibits the same error message in its question):

```
wsl.exe ~ -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

I suspect the path starting with `\\wsl$\...` is incirrectly interpreted by a bash session (with `$` being the prefix to variables, and would need to [be escaped in a path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876900/6309))